# State exists but not a function error happens. this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs

State is existing but "not a function error" happens.

I am developing a component with React Tag.
The function is exists

I have no idea what it is wrong..

Error says
TypeError: this.setState is not a function

[image]

```
class ReagtTagSample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tags: [{ id: 'Yugoslavia', text: 'Yugoslavia' }, { id: 'India', text: 'India' }],
      suggestions: [
        { id: "England", text: "England" },
        { id: "Mexico", text: "Mexico" },
      ],
    };


  handleAddition(tag) {
    this.setState((state) => ({ tags: [...state.tags, tag] }));
  }

  handleDrag(tag, currPos, newPos) {
    const tags = [...this.state.tags];
    const newTags = tags.slice();

    newTags.splice(currPos, 1);
    newTags.splice(newPos, 0, tag);
    this.setState({ tags: newTags });
  }
```

```
  render() {
    const { test } = this.props;
    const { tags, suggestions } = this.state;
            <ReactTags
              tags={tags}
              suggestions={suggestions}
              handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
              handleAddition={this.handleAddition}
              handleDrag={this.handleDrag}
              delimiters={delimiters}
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

`handleAddition` should be an arrow function to rebind `this` otherwise is not a class reference

```
 handleAddition = (tag) => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ tags: [...state.tags, tag] }));
  }
```

same applies for `handleDrag`